# html form validation not working

Tags: html, validation

I was working on a html form where I have to enter user information and on submit. It will navigate to the php connection page. The problem is that I have been trying to validate the data before submitting through JavaScript and it's not happening.

Below I am posting the HTML form code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script language = "JavaScript">
        function validate()
        {
            var username = document.getElementById("userName").value;
            var password = document.getElementById("Password").value;
            var repassword = document.getElementById("RePassword").value;

            if (username.length < 0) {
                alert("Please enter the username.");
                return false;
            }
            if (password == null || password == "") {
                alert("Please enter the password.");
                return false;
            }
             if (repassword == null || repassword == "" || repassword != password) {
                alert("Please enter the password.");
                return false;
            }


        } 
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="frmMr" action="send_post.php" method="post"  onsubmit="return(validate());">
    User Name:<br> <input type="text" name="userName"><br>
    Enter Password:<br> <input type="text" name="Password"><br>
    Reenter Password:<br> <input type="text" name="RePassword"><br>
    <input type="submit" >
</form>
<p id="error_para" ></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your input fields don't have id's, so getElementById returns null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTML didn't have `id` tag, whereas in Javascript you are using `getElementById('')`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
// Changed the script syntax
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        var username = document.getElementById("userName").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("Password").value;
        var repassword = document.getElementById("RePassword").value;

        if (username.length <= 0) {
            alert("Please enter the username.");
            return false;
        }
        if (password == null || password == "") {
            alert("Please enter the password.");
            return false;
        }
         if (repassword == null || repassword == "" || repassword != password) {
            // Changed Password message for testing
            alert("Confirm Password empty or do not match.");
            return false;
        }
    } 
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="frmMr" action="send_post.php" method="post"  onsubmit="return(validate());">
        User Name:<br> <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName"><br>
        Enter Password:<br> <input type="text" id="Password" name="Password"><br>
        Reenter Password:<br> <input type="text" id="RePassword" name="RePassword"><br>
       <!-- Added id="" attribute to above 3 lines -->
       <input type="submit" >
   </form>
   <p id="error_para" ></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add IDS to all the fields

```
 <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName">
```

and so...

Answer (score 2):

I would also suggest using `required` attribute for inputs in HTML5.

```
<input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" required>
```

It marks the field to be required (as the name says) and the form won't submit if there is no value in it.

Comment: Thank you. Required is useful but in case of password matching, you can't use it. So opted for normal validation.

Comment: Well, think of it this way, you still need to have password and re-password fields to be required, so use html5 functionality for that. For matching them you can use javascript. In web development, it is always a good idea to implement as many levels of security as possible. In this case 3, client side in html and javascript, and one on server side, just in case that somebody finds a way around it.

Comment: Thank you. I have added them too.

Answer (score -2):

finally, `return true;` at the end of your function

Comment: It is a fix for a bug in his method, but it is not a solution to his question.